# Boot Issues After 21.10 Upgrade

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, csm

After upgrading one of my Ubuntu systems to 21.10, it now boots only to the BIOS. It appears to be a UEFI issue which is what I believe in my BIOS is called CSM boot mode which is enabled. In order to boot, I needed to create a USB boot as the DVD I created did not boot properly.

Booting to the Live USB and installing gParted, I can see that there is an EFI partition and the Ubuntu partition but I’m not sure how to repair GRUB from here. I tried installing boot-repair but it fails every time. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

After spending days trying to get this going, it finally works again! The first thing was to create an Ubuntu Live USB drive which was necessary as no Live DVD would actually boot. After creating the USB, I tried to install `boot-repair` but again it was to no avail as it simply would not install. Therefore I downloaded the ISO and created a bootable `boot-repair` USB which when run fixed the boot issue! Of course, it put on an older xubuntu theme so I've got to figure out how to install the proper one but it least it boots now.

Comment: how can I use the boot-repair? in safe mode?

Comment: If you create bootable boot-repair media, it takes care of the mode and doesn’t even give an option.